# Timber plugin with term (WordPress)

Tags: wordpress, twig, timber

I have a list of posts with one term assigned for one post.

I have 5 terms. I generated a list of the term used. I would like to display only post with the same term in my archive page.

**archive.php :**

```
$templates = array( 'archive.twig', 'index.twig' );

$context = Timber::get_context();
$context['categories'] = Timber::get_terms('category', array('hide_empty' => true));

$context['title'] = 'Archive';
if ( is_day() ) {
    $context['title'] = 'Archive: '.get_the_date( 'D M Y' );
} else if ( is_month() ) {
    $context['title'] = 'Archive: '.get_the_date( 'M Y' );
} else if ( is_year() ) {
    $context['title'] = 'Archive: '.get_the_date( 'Y' );
} else if ( is_tag() ) {
    $context['title'] = single_tag_title( '', false );
} else if ( is_category() ) {
    $context['title'] = single_cat_title( '', false );
    array_unshift( $templates, 'archive-' . get_query_var( 'cat' ) . '.twig' );
} else if ( is_post_type_archive() ) {
    $context['title'] = post_type_archive_title( '', false );
    array_unshift( $templates, 'archive-' . get_post_type() . '.twig' );
}

$context['posts'] = Timber::get_posts();

Timber::render( $templates, $context );
```

In my **home.twig** file where all post are display :

```
<ul class="category--list">
  {% for cat in categories %}
     <li><a href="{{cat.link}}" class="h-cat">{{cat.name}}</a></li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

What loop must I create in my "archive.twig" file to only display post in a term clicked ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Jardon, first step is to get the relevant term...

**archive.php**

```
$context['term'] = new Timber\Term(); 
//this will fetch whichever term is in the scope of that php file
```

then you just need to send it over to the twig file for display...

**archive.twig**

```
<h2>{{ term.name }}</h2>
```